# Simple modification to OpenCart theme

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, opencart

I'm using the Shoppica theme with OpenCart. I'd like to make a modification to the category page. It gives a description (which I entered in the backend) and than a list of products follow.

In category.tpl it says:

```
<?php if ($description) echo $description; ?>
```

But I'd like to have an extra description, let's call it description2. This should come AFTER the list of products.
In PhpMyAdmin I added another row in *oc_category_description* and called it description2
Manually (so in PhpMyAdmin) I filled this with text.

Now I placed the following in the category.tpl file:

```
<?php if ($description2) echo $description2; ?>
```

But now I receive an error:

> undefined variable: description2 in
>   /home/.../public_html/catalog/view/theme/shoppica2/template/product/category.tpl
>   on line 187

Any idea, what I did wrong. Do I need to declare it somewhere else (in another file? where?)

Answer (score 3):

There is need of understanding of the MVC pattern which is OpenCart built in.

Briefly - You have a Model class that interacts with the database, a Controller class that operates above and calls Model methods (data retrieval, data update, data insertion) and pass the output to the brwoser while it is processed by the View (should be another class but OpenCart has only like MC - Model-Controller part with template files).

So to Your problem: You have to modify `catalog/model/catalog/category.php` and look for method called `getCategory` that retrieves the concrete category data. Here in select query should be `select * from ...` - if it is so, everything is OK, but if it is like `select category_id, category_description, ... from ...` then You have to add Your new field here as well (sorry, I do not remember the SQL queries from OpenCart).

Additionaly edit the `catalog/controller/product/category.php` and look for the part where the category data is controlled (the category model is called) or look for line that starts with `$this->data['description'] = ...;` and add Your new field here, like `$this->data['description2'] = ...;`.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Well explained. This is the best way to do this as doing quick fix SQL calls within the code is the wrong approach. Plus 1

Comment: There is no specific need to understand the MVC pattern, just the fact that the software is not magically translating every column to a variable (which indeed user1409956 suspected). It's entirely possible that OpenCart could, even if it actually used an MVC pattern, make every data column available as a variable to the template. +1 anyway.

Comment: @PaulGregory That's good point, indeed. Anyway although I'm not quite happy with how OpenCart deals with resources and with how much has to be done to make something done, I still love OpenCart and consider it as the best open source e-commerce platform for developers (and clients, too :-) ).

Comment: This worked out great. Thanks! The only thing: If I change anything in the backend to any other field (like description, or meta tags), the description2 field changes as well (gets overwritten), the description2 field turns blank again. Any quick way to fix this, or should I add `$entry_description2` in the category_form.tpl (in Admin/View/../catalog/)?

Comment: Yes, you will need do to something very similar for the admin files. Edit the controller and model, but remember there will be a function in the model for writing to the table and another function to retrieve the data. Don't forget to add your entry to the language file too!