# Second Variable For Product

Tags: php, opencart

I'm using Opencart am trying to call a variable to be displayed just under the product name in the featured module. This featured module is displayed on the frontpage.

I've already added a new column in the database and was able to add data into the db through the admin page. Verified by going through PHPmyadmin.

I can't however, display the variable on the main page. I've edited catalog/view/theme/*/template/module/featured.tpl to include the following code but with no success. If i remove the isset it throws an Notice: Undefined variable: product_description in ... error

**Addded the following line**

```
<div class="secondtitle"><?php echo isset($product_description['secondtitle']); ?></a></div>
```

**Before**

```
<div class="name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></div>
```

**VQmod**

```
<file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/module/featured.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search position="after"><![CDATA[
            <div class="name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></div>
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            <div class="secondtitle"><?php echo isset($product_description['secondtitle']); ?></a></div>
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
```

Can anyone please guide me on how to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple modification to OpenCart theme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401924/simple-modification-to-opencart-theme)

Comment: Read my answer in the post from the comment above - it should explain what is needed to be done.

Comment: Are you pulling the column from the product description and then passing it into the product array?

Comment: thanks shadyyx and Jay for your response.

Comment: @shadyyx i've tried editing the catalog/controller/product/product.php to include $this->data['secondtitle'] = html_entity_decode($product_info['secondtitle'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); and added 'secondtitle'    => $query->row['secondtitle'], in catalog/model/catalog/product.php but the problem persists. am i doing it correctly? Sorry not much of a programmer. thanks in advance.

Comment: @JayGilford sorry I couldn't reply to you as stackoverflow was on maintenance when I tried. I guess that would be a 'yes' to your question. What i did was added a new column in product_description called secondtitle. i managed to push some data into those columns but having difficulties getting them out to display beneath product titles on the featured product frontpage. do you happen to have any quick fixes to this? thanks.

Comment: @shadyyx tried clearing the cache but still error out hmm ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more specific, it is hard to guess where did you add the extra field in the database. Is it in the 'product' table?
Then, based on your previous comment, looks like you're on the right track.

You need to edit model/catalog/product.php Edit function getProduct()

You'll see an array being populated like:

```
'product_id'       => $query->row['product_id'],
'name'             => $query->row['name'],
'description'      => $query->row['description'],
...
```

Add your custom field there:

```
'secondtitle'      => $query->row['secondtitle']
```

Can you please show where in the DB you are adding this custom variable?

[EDITED: 2012-12-13 in response to the comment #1]

If your custom field is in 'product_description' table then follow the above example to edit model/catalog/product.php
Edit controller featured.php, add your variable to the products array. Look for

```
$this->data['products'][] = array(
    'product_id' => $product_info['product_id'],
    'thumb'      => $image, 
    ...
```

Add your field

```
     ...
    'secondtitle'=> $product_info['secondtitle']
```

Then in view featured.tpl echo it where you want it with

```
<?php echo $product['secondtitle']; ?>
```

This works, I just tested it.
You were doing the right thing as I said before, probably just missed a step or two..

Comment: sorry should have been more specific. I've added a secondtitle to oc_product_description table. Would it be possible to post a vqmod here as it would be easier to track the changes.

Comment: I edited my answer based on your comment. You can easily setup vQmod file for this.

Comment: Hi @B-and-P, I'm trying to expand this to both latest as well as categories page, but for some reason it no longers gets displayed on those pages. do you happen to know why?

I'm pretty sure it works becuase when i tested without the php echo it works. Could this be the array in model/catalog/product.php?

Comment: @Porkribz Sorry, I don't follow, should work the same. Maybe post a new question with code examples?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this, as I was displaying the second title on the featured module, i just had to call it up on featured.php and voila it's showing now. Thanks everyone for your help.